# Why is wget saving something when using parametrized url?

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I am using following command in my bash script to trigger jenkins build:

```
wget --no-check-certificate "http://<jenkins_url>/view/some_view/job/some_prj/buildWithParameters?token=xxx"
```

Output:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 201 Created
Length: 0
Saving to: “buildWithParameters?token=xxx”

[ <=>                                                                                                                                                                       ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-02-20 10:10:46 (0.00 B/s) - “buildWithParameters?token=xxx” saved [0/0]
```

And then it's creates empty file: “buildWithParameters?token=xxx”

My question is: why wget creates this file and how to turn that functionality off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simply:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O /dev/null http://foo
```

this will make `wget` save the file to `/dev/null`, effectively discarding it.